# Image switches location in web-mail clients (gmail)

Tags: html, css, gmail, mailchimp

So i've got a problem regarding my image on my website. I have an image in a container and it extends a bit to the right. This is all fine and dandy and works great in all mail clients except the web based ones (i tested hotmail and gmail). Images below to clarify.

The right situation (in a mail client (i used the default mac mail program)) : http://prntscr.com/38xtbr

The wrong situation (in this case in the web version of gmail) : http://prntscr.com/38xtf2

As you can see the image doesn't wrap around the page anymore as it does in any other mail client. Is there a fix for this or is this something that is new to everyone?

```
<td valign="top" width="195" class="sidebarContent" mc:edit="sidebar_content">
    <img style="position: relative; left: 30px; width: 195px;height: 44px;border: 0;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none; background-image: none !important;" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/f8e390cb608890835535cf525/images/bekijk67e9c3.png">
</td>


.sidebarContent{
            /*@editable*/ color:#303030;
            /*@editable*/ font-family:Helvetica;
            /*@editable*/ font-size:13px;
            /*@editable*/ line-height:150%;
            /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
right bottom,
left top,
color-stop(0.65, #FFFFFF),
color-stop(0.77, #EFEFEF)

        }

        }

        /**
        * @tab Sidebar
        * @section sidebar link
        * @tip Set the styling for your email's sidebar links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
        */
        .sidebarContent a:link, .sidebarContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .sidebarContent a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
            /*@editable*/ color:#E95497;
            /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
            /*@editable*/ text-decoration:underline;
            }

        .sidebarContent img{
            display:inline;
            height:auto;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
right bottom,
left top,
color-stop(0.65, #FFFFFF),
color-stop(0.77, #EFEFEF)
```

);

Comment: did you use external CSS or placing <style> tag? Many webmail such as GMail doesn't support those type of CSS, you should use inline CSS styling

Comment: I'll add my code to show you what my current styling is.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail and Yahoo web clients don't support the positioning so well. Both of them don't use the 'left' property you are you are trying to use on the image.
I think you should create wider image (be it in png format) an give it a transparent background on the left side, so it is wider and placed properly.

A little bit of cheat sheet for email coding --> http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/